unrecognized option `-fdiagnostics-color=always'
i want to code C++ with VScode. But after correctly installing and setting up gcc(at least the cmd can correctly output its version), i got errors like in title when trying to run the helloWorld.
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && c:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe 
D:\workspace\c++new\HellowWorld.cpp -o D:\workspace\c++new\HellowWorld.exe
c:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe: unrecognized option `-fdiagnostics-color=always'
Use `c:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe --help' for a complete list of options.

I find this arg in task.json created by vscode.
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gdb.exe build active file",
        "command": "c:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "c:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    },
...
#other alternatives which should be irrevant
]

And tried to run without it(solution from Is gcc -fdiagnostics-colour working on Windows?)
A similiar error occured complaining about "-g", after deleting that, again with "-o".
Without all these, the program runned, but never ends and have no output. And I still find a complaint
"D:\workspace\c++new\HellowWorld.cpp": not in executable format: file format not 
recognized
D:\workspace\c++new\HellowWorld.exe: No such file or directory.


It appears that you have not correctly configured VSCode to work with gcc.  You may have missed one-or-more steps in the configuration directions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

This is a build task, not a launch debugger task. gdb.exe cannot build C++ code.

OK, i figured out.  Use g++ for build. I just deleted all config files for the project and use g++ and it all worked. Thanks for solving my dumb problem!
